# Can any follower evangelize a religion?

Tags: civilization-6

Founders of a religion can have their apostles use the "evangelize belief" option to add beliefs to a religion, until all the slots are filled. Can a non-founder of a religion who has had a city converted also use an apostle to evangelize, if there are slots open, or is that option only available to the founders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my current game, I did not earn a religion, but I knocked out Russia after they had converted some of my cities.

I am unable to either Evangelize or Launch Inquisition for my adopted Religion.